# ¿Cómo se obtiene únicamente el último tuit de una cuenta específica?

Tags: python, twitter, twitter-api, tweepy

estoy haciendo un bot para responderle a un usuario específico con un tuit, cada vez que publica.
El problema que tengo es básicamente que Tweepy recolecta muchísimos tuits de la persona y yo solamente quiero responderle al último tuit que haya publicado la persona.
El código que tengo es éste.
¿Qué puedo agregarle para recolectar solamente un tuit (el último)?

```
import tweepy

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)

api = tweepy.API(auth)
user = api.get_user('cuentaX')

print ("INICIADO CORRECTAMENTE","\nRESPONDIENDO","\n --------------------")

public_tweets = api.home_timeline()

for status in api.user_timeline(ID_CUENTAX):
    print (status.id)
    api.update_status('@cuentaX mensaje de respuesta', status.id)

print ("TWEETS RESPONDIDOS CORRECTAMENTE")
```

Comment: Este es un modelo de pregunta bien formulada.

Comment: Te dejo un link a una pregunta similar [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32022980/12580704)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según lo que entendí quieres ejecutarlo una vez por terminal y que responda al último, correcto?

Según [la documentación](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/api.html#API.user_timeline) deberías cambiar tu ciclo por

```
status = api.user_timeline(ID_CUENTAX, count=1)
if len(status) > 0:
    last_tweet = status[0]
    print(last_tweet.id)
    api.update_status('@cuentaX mensaje de respuesta', last_tweet.id)
```

Lo importante a notar es que la función `user_timeline`, retorna una lista de estados siempre, esta puede estar vacía o tener el último tweet, por lo que debes asegurarte que contiene el tweet antes de ocupar `update_status`

Ojalá te sirva!